# How to evaluate stored column name in dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to extract the value from a data frame column by using a column reference that is stored in a data frame variable.  That is, with input data frame:

```
  g1 g2 Group
1  a  d    g1
2  b  e    g1
3  c  f    g2
```

I would like to create a new column using the `Group` column to specify which values from either `g1` or `g2` to pull.  Desired output:

```
  g1 g2 Group Group_val
1  a  d    g1         a
2  b  e    g1         b
3  c  f    g2         f
```

Based on other answers on SO, I'm trying to use the standard evaluation form of mutate with `as.name`, `quote`, or lazyeval's `interp` functions, but I haven't figured out the right call to get the column reference to actually evaluate:

```
df <- data.frame("g1" = c('a', 'b' , 'c'), "g2" = c('d', 'e', 'f'), "Group"=c("g1", "g1", "g2"))
df <- mutate_(df, Group_val = as.name("Group"))
```

just populates `Group_val` with the `Group` values.  I've also used `match` to populate `Group_val` with the right column indices (e.g.: 1, 1, 2), but obviously that's just another form of the same problem.

I'd like to figure this out in dplyr syntax, but I'm open to non-dplyr solutions if there's something easier.

Comment: This has been asked here numerous times. Have you tried `df[cbind(1:nrow(df), df$Group)]`?

Comment: Thanks David.  This is helpful.  (I'm sure it has been asked before, but I did spend a fair amount of time looking and didn't find it.)  On my larger data, I was getting an index out of bounds from this call, and it proved easier to use match to get the column number and use that as the second argument to cbind in your solution.  If anyone happens to post a dplyr solution, I'm still interested since dplyr syntax is a little more straightforward to debug and I'd like to figure out if quote/eval/etc. could be used.

Comment: This should work for *any* data set. Unless you have something messed up in your data set like your data set is of class `tbl_df`